# error setup ta-lib Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL

Tags: python, installation, ta-lib

when i try to install ta-lib i have this problem, nonetheless i installed before talib($ brew install talib)
Thank you for help or a hint....

```
$ pip install ta-lib
Collecting ta-lib
  Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.24.tar.gz (269 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from ta-lib) (1.21.5)
Building wheels for collected packages: ta-lib
  Building wheel for ta-lib (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      skipping 'talib/_ta_lib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
      In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:6:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/stdio.h:32:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/sys/cdefs.h:758:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:6:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:27:5: error: "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
      #   error "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
          ^
      In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:6:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:30:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/string.h:41:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/sys/types.h:78:10: fatal error: 'machine/types.h' file not found
      #include <machine/types.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@9/9.0.1_4/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ta-lib
  Running setup.py clean for ta-lib
Failed to build ta-lib
Installing collected packages: ta-lib
  Running setup.py install for ta-lib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for ta-lib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      skipping 'talib/_ta_lib.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
      In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:6:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/stdio.h:32:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/sys/cdefs.h:758:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:6:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:27:5: error: "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
      #   error "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
          ^
      In file included from talib/_ta_lib.c:6:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:30:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/string.h:41:
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/sys/types.h:78:10: fatal error: 'machine/types.h' file not found
      #include <machine/types.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      3 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@9/9.0.1_4/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

Comment: what `uname -a` prints?

Comment: hello, this is the answer:  Darwin iMac-de-Marc.local 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Fri Mar 18 00:45:05 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: It seems python tries to compile the C code with `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm@9/9.0.1_4/bin/clang` compiler which is apparently mis-configured. How you build it from sources? Do you really need llvm?